# Two ImageViews appear in Navigation header while I set only one in xml

Tags: android, xml, view, imageview, navigation-drawer

So I am experiencing a very weird behaviour. I have a `NavigationDrawer` and inside it I have my navigation header, which has a facebook `ProfilePictureView` and a `TextView`.

The problem is, when I run my app there are **TWO ProfileImageViews** in the navigation header. Even though in Android Studio, the preview of the header xml displays one `ProfileImageView` correctly.

I've attached a screenshot below:

[image]

And here is my code for `nav_header_home.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@color/dark_blue"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I initialise it:

```
View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);
usernameTextView = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
profileImage = (ProfilePictureView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

---

And here is **another weird behaviour** that may help figure out the problem:

**When I initialise `ProfilePictureView` like this:**

`profileImage = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);`

Then set an image to the view, the view at the top displays the image.

**Whereas if I initialise like this:**

`profileImage = (ProfilePictureView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);`

Then the view at the bottom displays the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I figured out the problem. The line `View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);` does not seem to **get** the current `header`, instead it seems to **inflate and create** a new one, which is likely the cause of my `ProfilePictureView` being added twice!

Replacing it with `View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);` works! It correctly **gets** the current header!